# Azure service bus multiple instances for the same subscriber

Tags: asp.net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a situation where I have an asp.net core application which registers a subscription client to a topic on startup (`IHostedService`), this subscription client essentially has a dictionary of callbacks that need to be fired whenever it detects a new message in a topic with an id (this id is stored on the message properties). This dictionary lives throughout the lifetime of the application, and is in memory.

Everything works fine on a single instance of the asp.net core app service on azure, as soon as I scale up to 2, I notice that sometimes the callbacks in the subscription are not firing. This makes sense, as we have two instances now, each with its own dictionary store of callbacks.

So I updated the code to check if the id of the subscription exists, if not, abandon message, if yes, get the callback and invoke it.

```
public async Task HandleMessage(Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var queueItem = this.converter.DeserializeItem(message);

    var sessionId = // get the session id from the message
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId))
    {
         await this.subscriptionClient.AbandonAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
         return;
    }

    if (!this.subscriptions.TryGetValue(sessionId, out var subscription))
    {
        await this.subscriptionClient.AbandonAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
        return;
    }

    await subscription.Call(queueItem);

    // subscription was found and executed. Complete message
    await this.subscriptionClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
}
```

However, the problem still occurs. My only guess is that when calling `AbandonAsync`, the same instance is picking up the message again?

I guess what I am really trying to ask is, if I have multiple instances of a topic subscription client all pointing to the same subscriber for the topic, is it possible for all the instances to get a copy of the message? Or is that not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by making use of service bus sessions. What I was trying to do with the dictionary of callbacks is basically a session manager anyway!

Service bus sessions allow me to have multiple instances of a session client all pointing to the same subscription. However, each instance will only know or care about the sessions it is currently dealing with.

Answer (score 6):

> if I have multiple instances of a topic subscription client all pointing to the same subscriber for the topic, is it possible for all the instances to get a copy of the message? Or is that not guaranteed.

No. If it's the *same* subscription all clients are pointing to, only one will be receiving that message.

You're running into an issue of scaling out with competing consumers. If you're scaling out, you never know what instance will pick the message. And since your state is local (in memory of each instance), this will fail from time to time. Additional downside is the cost. By fetching messages on the "wrong" instance and abandoning, you're going to pay higher cost on the messaging side.

To address this issue you either need to have a shared/centralized or change your architecture around this.

Comment: Indeed. I just noticed microsoft have included a subset of the management apis in the dotnet core version of the service bus, in that case I will dynamically create a subscription as a new node starts :)

Comment: Also, could service bus sessions be used for my cause?

Comment: The only downside would be no scale out per session as only one consumer can handle a given session messages.

Comment: I think this is ok for my cause. As my sessions are fairly short lived. Thanks for all your advice!

Comment: @SeanFeldman I am using this way you describe it to work as the intended flow. I have 2 instances connecting to the same subscription name, and only 1 gets the message.  My issue is that I need to disconnect an instance so the other instance starts receiving all of the messages. I'm calling subscription.Close() on the subscriptionClient that is returned from SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString, but even after I call this I still don't receive every message on the remaining instance. Do you know of any way to fully disconnect an instance so it behaves as if that instance never existed

Comment: Closing is an expensive operation. If you expect messages to be distributed equally between the instances, it won't happen as Azure Service Bus doesn't do that. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your comment and it would be better to raise it as a separate question with all the details.

Comment: It's more a case of just needing not to lose any messages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020748/azure-service-bus-subscription-close-not-working-as-intended?noredirect=1#comment111444626_63020748

Comment: Messages are never lost. That's the beauty of Azure Service Bus