# Azure Service Bus subscription.close() not working as intended

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, azureservicebus

I have a scaled out application, where each instance connects to a azure service bus subscription with the same name. The end result being that only a single instance gets to act on any given message because they are all listening to the same subscription.

Occasionally the application needs to place an instance into an idle state (service fabric ActiveSecondary replica). When this occurs, I need to close the subscription so that this instance no longer receives messages. If there were 2 instances originally, once one gets placed into the idle state all message should go to the remaining instance. This is important so that all messages are handled by a properly configured primary instance.

When the instance becomes idle, a cancellation token is cancelled. I have code listening for the cancellation and calling Close() on the SubscriptionClient generated when I created the subscription originally.

The issue is, even after I call Close() on one instance, messages are still being randomly split between it and the primary.

Is the way I'm doing this inherently wrong, or is something else in my code causing this behavior?

Comment: Are you handling the change in `OnChangeRoleAsync`?

Comment: I am handling it in the cancellationtoken.Register delegate handler. Based on the service fabric lifecycle doc I assume any active secondary would have either been demoted (therefore token cancelled) or never had runasync called to begin with. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Could you post the subscribe/unsubscribe code?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Service Bus track 0 and 1 SDKs do not support CancellationTokens. If you're closing your client and messages won't be processed, they'd be picked up another competing instance when visible again. That's where `MaxLockDuration` and `MaxDeliveryCount` are important to ensure messages have enough processing attempts to account the situation you're describing w/o waiting for too long.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard this post. Turns out I had the same subscription name used twice within a single instance, so they were competing for the events. The close() function works as expected.